# Why is my camera movement not Lerping correctly?

Tags: unity

I am trying to move camera only on the x-axis based on a Swipe. I want it to move smoothly to the left or right. Right now, it seems to be simply be jumping a few pixels forward, and not Lerping at all. What am I doing wrong?

This script is attached directly to a Cinemachine camera.

Here is the code:

```
private void Update()
    {
        if (Touch.activeFingers.Count == 1) {
            var touch = Touch.activeTouches[0];

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
               
                startPos = touch.screenPosition;
                
            }

            

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended && coroutineAllowed)
            {
                endPos = touch.screenPosition;
                
            }
                 

            TriggerSwipe(startPos, endPos);
        }
    }

   
    private void TriggerSwipe(Vector2 start, Vector2 end)
    {
        Vector3 direction = end - start;
        Vector2 direction2D = new Vector2(direction.x, direction.y).normalized;

        if (direction != prevDirection)
        {
            if (Vector2.Dot(Vector2.left, direction2D) > directionThreshhold)
            {
                var targetPosition = new Vector3(start.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
                transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetPosition, Time.deltaTime);
            }

            if (Vector2.Dot(Vector2.right, direction2D) > directionThreshhold)
            {
                var targetPosition = new Vector3(-start.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
                transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetPosition, Time.deltaTime);
            }

            prevDirection = direction;
        }
```

Comment: Your function is called only once, consider a coroutine

Comment: Looks like you're making the common error of treating Lerp like a tweening routine that will continue to execute on subsequent frames after you invoke it once. But it's just a math function — if endPos and startPos are the same on subsequent frames, you skip the Lerp call and leave the object where it was after the first frame of the movement. [I've answered versions of this question a few times](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A39518+tweening), so you can find some strategies to correct this code in those existing answers.